# ReactJS - Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 27: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 27: Unexpected token .

Seems like there shouldn't be a "." after **this**

How can I fix it ?

Here is my whole code

```
var PageHandler = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            page: ''
        };
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            {this.state.page == '' && <MainPage />} // THIS IS LINE 27
        );
    }

});

var MainPage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="main-page">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);">Open</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And this is in my .html file

```
 <script type="text/jsx">
    //var PageHandler = React.createElement(PageHandler);
    //React.render(PageHandler, document.body);
    React.render(<PageHandler />, document.body);
    </script>
```

**EDIT**
And now I found out that if I add `<div>...</div>` it's working.

```
render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
            {this.state.page == '' && <MainPage />}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Why is it so ?

Comment: That line is syntactically incorrect. It's hard to say what it should be instead because it's not clear what you're trying to express. You've got what looks like an expression (except for the embedded HTML markup) inside `{ }`, and that's just not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The render method in react must return a single parent element. When you think about what it will compile the jsx to, it's easier to see why it's having a hard time. [createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) takes these arguments:

```
createElement(
  string/ReactClass type,
  [object props],
  [children ...]
)
```

So your MainPage will compile to:

```
return(
            React.createElement("div", {className: "main-page"}, 
              React.createElement("a", {href: "javascript:void(0);"}, "Open")
            )
```

It can easily see that it creates a `div`, props are just the class name, child is an `a`.

But looking at

```
{this.state.page == '' && <MainPage />}
```

What will that compile to? What will the first parameter be? It doesn't have a clear type for the element it's going to create. When you wrap it all in a div, it does and it will compile to this:

```
React.createElement("div", null, 
            this.state.page == '' && React.createElement(MainPage, null), " // THIS IS LINE 27"
)
```

Of course, that may not be what you intend it to do but hopefully it shows what React is trying to do.